# How can I debug a crash without any crash logs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, nodemon

My company gave me a project in Sails JS which was written by another company. It randomly crashes without any crash log. Sometimes in 10 minutes, sometimes in 4 hours.

```
// There is no error information here.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Is there any way to find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to run it not using nodemon?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly (like @Jake Weary suggested), don't use nodemon for debugging, as it suppresses a lot of the error messages.

Take a look at [node-inspector on GitHub](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), it's very useful for stepping through  your code.

Also, see the official node documentation on debugging, here: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Finally, I often still find it useful, when all else has failed to use the [legacy-debugger](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/), though it is officially deprecated